# WCF/silverlight end points

Tags: wcf, silverlight, cross-domain

I have an issue which I'm trying to overcome, i'm away this is possible but im not sure how.

I have the following config in my service

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_MyDataService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mywebsite.com/vdir/Services/MyDataService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_MyDataService"
            contract="HBDataLayer.MyDataService" name="CustomBinding_MyDataService" />          
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The issue is the end point address, i have the address set to the actually published location however when im trying to debug locally i get a crossdomain policy issue. I have to constantly update this config file switching between localhost and the website.

I have been told that its possible to configure it so you don't have this problem.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue all the time while developing Silverlight applications, you need to place the ClientAccessPolicy.xml and CrossDomain.xml on your server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx